# Activate click in iFrame when clicking element in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to activate the click event of an element within an iFrame (a standard twitter follow button) when clicking on an element within my main page.

Here's the code I'm trying to use which does not work...

```
$(".twit-test").click( function() {
    $('.twitter-follow-button').contents().find('#follow-button').click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That's a pretty annoying thing. Luckily you cannot abuse your users like this.

Comment: do you own the iframe content ?

Comment: I'm not trying to fool anyone into clicking a twitter link, I just don't like the look of the standard follow link

Comment: Not unless he "owns" twitter. @Tom: Those links/buttons should have the same look&feel on all sites; that's why you cannot specify a custom style.

Comment: Ah... since I don't own twitter I guess I'm on to a loser!

Comment: I am pretty sure you can just change the follow button image.

Comment: @Kevin Wang - If that's possible then that'd be great. How do I do this though?

Comment: If you can use js to edit the contents of the iframe, than sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by a few people above, I can't achieve what I was asking because I am not the owner of the iFrame content.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried,

```
$(".twit-test").click( function() {
    $('.twitter-follow-button').contents().find('#follow-button').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I dare say this would work but I have the problem of not being the owner of the iFrame I'm trying to trigger the click of.

Comment: This is literally the same thing as OP's code, except you're using `trigger('click')` instead of `click()`, but they're synonyms.

Comment: My mistake, I took other meaning from the jQuery API documentation: "In the first two variations, this method is a shortcut for .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7. In the third variation, when .click() is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click")." - http://api.jquery.com/click/.  It seems to suggest that before 1.7 this was not the case.